# howto change group ownership of directory with normal permission

Tags: linux, file, permissions

In Ubuntu an user (user_a belonging to group_a) creates a new directory 'new_dir'.
The ownership of this directory is ofcourse user_a.group_a
The user is also part of group_b

My question is, why can user_a not change the group ownership to group_b (without using sudo or su) although user_a is part of group_b as well?

```
chgrp user_a.group_b new_dir results in an error
```

Comment: How about `chgrp  group_b new_dir`?

Comment: Same problem, no permission to change ownership

Comment: hmmm... don't have machine to try out.  How about `chown user_a:group_b new_dir`?

Comment: the syntax you propose is ok, but the permission problem remains.

Comment: Have you checked the permissions/ownership (group and/or user) that new_dir is in

Comment: yes, it lists user_a.group_a  It all works fine when I prepend the command with sudo. Wat I do not understand is why a user that is a member of group_b too can not change the ownership of a directory to that group.

Comment: 'chgrp group_b new_dir' works fine on a Debian Squeeze box (kernel 2.6.37), whatever the directory rights or the rights of its parent directory.(user_a is modified with 'usermod user_a -G group_b'). What's your version? Could it be SELinux related?

Comment: `chgrp group_b new_dir` seems to work on Linux Mint 12 (3.x kernel)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do that on **every** gnu/linux systems.

In fact, some distro required that only **super user** can do this type of operation.

Moreover, if you are in a group and add yourself (or someone adds you) and you dind't restart or log off - log in since that happened, you have to run a command  - hope to remember well - like that: `newgrp <group>`.

That's because groups don't update until you log-in again. So even if you edit /etc/groups, you still have to "reload" it